# Creating a cross platform object model

Tags: android, ios, poco-libraries

Im trying to create a single object model that i can distrubute to ios, android and webserver. Either by porting a single source..or using c++ as a lcd language.

Biz logic , poco and data only...no ui.
This biz layer must be acceable from native os (swift ios) (android java).
Xamarim runs inside a seprate runtime...so will not work from what i can see

What are my best options for porting from a single source?

Answer (score 0):

C#.Net works in Windows, Linux (with [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/)) and Andriod (With [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/platform)). Micro$osft just [purchased](http://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2016/02/24/microsoft-to-acquire-xamarin-and-empower-more-developers-to-build-apps-on-any-device/) Xamarin and integrated it into Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I looked at that...but it requires the ui to also be made through xamarin...i need biz layer to be exposed to each seprate  os...the ui will be native